# Wordpress - moving a site to another domain, 301 redirects

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I moved a wordpress site to another domain. I want to preserve the google links however and help it re-index the new site.

I did a 301 redirect but it only works for the root director. When someone goes to `http://oldsite.com/directory/post-name-here/` I want them to be forwarded to `http://newsite.com/directory2/post-name-here/`. Both websites are in subdirectories. Is there a way to do it with in PHP? Or would I need a mod-rewrite?

---

What finally worked for me was this:

My oldsite file structure is like so:

```
/public_html/
     index.php
     /development/
         .htaccess
```

To recap, I wanted to forward everything coming into the development directory to the new website. This is the code of the .htaccess in the `development` directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.org$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://newsite.com/newdirectory/$1   [R=301,L]
```

Thank you so much to Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has always worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this rule to .htaccess file see below.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NEWDOMAIN.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already tried this and it didn't work. It successfully redirects the one directory, but not all the posts, and it doesn't redirect properly with the directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one link under the directory. You can add a index.php file to http://oldsite.com/directory/ with this code.

```
header("location: http://newsite.com/directory2/post-name-here/", true, 301);
```

If you have many links under the directory, then use the following code

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]=="/directory/post-name-here/"){
    header("location: http://newsite.com/directory2/post-name-here/", true, 301);
}
```

Here, we check if the file name is the old link, then redirect to new domain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried doing this with regex and another htaccess, but had too much trouble